# SEO - Can Google Crawl Text Inside jQuery Function?

Tags: jquery, seo

In an attempt to make my job easier I've developed a prototype that can be updated by users who wouldn't necessarily have the skills required to update my code.

This way the HTML can be left alone and all that needs to be updated are variables that update links, text and images.

So my question is, would Google be able to crawl this as they usually would if it was put in manually?

```
<a id="banner"></a>

var $banner = $('#banner');

var bannerTxt = "Banner Title";
var bannerUrl = "/banner-url";

$banner.attr('title', bannerTxt);
$banner.html("<h2>" + bannerTxt + "</h2>");
$banner.attr('href', bannerUrl);
```

I've fiddled it to explain it easier: http://jsfiddle.net/n7ubdnx7/

Comment: short answer: yes :)

Comment: Nobody can say for certain. They *might* index it, and as @JohnConde points out, they claim that they should; but the only way to be sure is to let them index your page and search for those keywords. What you should be thinking about is the (admittedly small) number of browsers that have JavaScript disabled for their own reasons.

Comment: If the "jquery function" places the text on the page, it might crawl it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google now processes JavaScript](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html) so it would be safe to assume they can index that content.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put your seo javascript to separate file into directory and close it using robots.txt

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Hope this hepls you